# Swiper пагинация

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, swiper

[image: Скриншот]

У меня есть три точки, три слайда и по сути, когда листаешь класс active он дожен изменять цвет выбранной точки. На жёлтый как на примере. Но этого не происходит.

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  background-color: blue;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-block">
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
import {Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, Swiper} from "swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm";

Swiper.use([Pagination, Navigation, Autoplay]);

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
  },
});
```

Comment: о, спасибо за Swiper.use!

Comment: Потому-что вы не тому элементу задаёте цвет, сами посмотрите на картинке ширина и высота элемента 0х0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: #f9ff00 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Использую сборку Андрея Горохова по этому подключить карусель такм образом не удалось
https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulp-scss-starter

Comment: @FrencOlesov так, а как я вам помогу, если вы не предоставили свои исходники?

Comment: Предоставил так как скинул сборку, все фалы для разработки находятся в папке src осталось их подключить. Только я вот не знаю как.